# Android : what's the different between view.getX() ane view.getTranslationX()

Tags: android, view

what's the different between view.getX() ane view.getTranslationX()?

Answer (score 0):

getX() defines the The visual x position of particular view, in pixels.

getTranslationX() defines The horizontal location of particular  view relative to its left position.

for more information, refer [read here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Answer (score 0):

getX() returns x position of view relative to its immediate parent.

getTranslationX() returns the horizontal translation of the view relative to its left position initially.